# trap exec return code in shell script

Tags: shell, error-handling, exec

I have to run a command using exec in a shell script, and I need to trap the exit code in case of error and run another command e.g

```
#!/bin/sh
set +e
exec command_that_will_fail
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "command failed, running another command"
fi
```

I understand that exec replaces the current shell and carries on, my problem is that I need to run another command if the exec is not sucessfull.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if there's some immediate error when it tries to run the process:

```
$ echo 1
1
$ echo $?
0
$ exec asd123
-bash: exec: asd123: not found
$ echo $?
127
```

If the executable file was found, and is started, then it will not return, because it will overtake the whole script and never return to bash again.

For example this never returns:

```
$ exec grep asd /dev/null
```

(the exit code of grep is 1, but the parent shell is overtaken, so nobody can check)

If you want to get an exit code from the process in this case, you have to start it as a subprocess, i.e. not using exec (just `command_that_will_fail`). In this case the bash process will act as a supervisor that waits until the subprocess finishes and can inspect the exit code.

Comment: The command has to use exec, since it is inside a docker-entrypoint script (I belive exec is used so that is continues as PID=1 )

Comment: That's even worse. Usually PID=1 is init (the root process). If it dies, the system dies, there's no exit code.

Comment: Why do you need your process as PID=1? What is the process? Why do you need the exit code, what are you going to do with it?

Comment: This script runs as the entrypoint of a docker container the idea was that in case of problems try an alternative but still run the container

Comment: I still don't get it. Why can't the bash script be the entrypoint with PID=1, your real process be a subprocess with some PID=222, and if it dies with an error you spawn an alternative with some PID=333?